# Xcode Swift programatically set UITextfield X position to center

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I have tried to center my textfield`s X position to be in center of my pageviewcontroller.
This is how I now have programmed it :

```
  lastnamefield =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100.33, y:431.33 , width: 206, height: 34))
        lastnamefield.backgroundColor = .clear
        lastnamefield.placeholder = "Last name"
        lastnamefield.textColor = .black
        lastnamefield.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 20)
        lastnamefield.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
          lastnamefield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
          lastnamefield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
          lastnamefield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
          lastnamefield.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
          lastnamefield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
      //  lastnamefield.delegate = self as! UITextFieldDelegate
          self.view.addSubview(lastnamefield)






    emailfield =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100.33, y:488 , width: 206, height: 34))
        emailfield.backgroundColor = .clear
        emailfield.placeholder = "Email Adress"
        emailfield.textColor = .black
        emailfield.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 20)
        emailfield.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
          emailfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
          emailfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
          emailfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
          emailfield.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
          emailfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
      //  emailfield.delegate = self as! UITextFieldDelegate
          self.view.addSubview(emailfield)
```

I know this obviously won't center it but I have tried things like this to :

```
emailfield.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: revealingSplashView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
emailfield.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
emailfield.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

My app either crashes or gets an error.. Im a little new to this constraints stuff and I have to do it programatically as my pageviewcontroller is programatically too.
I apologize for my bad writing skills. I'm not English.

Comment: Please share your crashlog and error messages.

Comment: And to center a view in its super view, you could simply try `lastnamefield.center = view.center`

Answer (score 0):

1- This will crash

```
emailfield.delegate = self as! UITextFieldDelegate
```

instead do

```
emailfield.delegate = self
```

and make the vc conforms

```
class VC:UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
```

2-

When  adding constraints don't forget to set

```
self.emailfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

3- to the email you set width , height and centerX and you also need to set a y constraint centerY , top or bottom

Comment: there is no such thing called centerX and centerY? What should I write? This didn't work :   lastnamefield =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: centerX, y:centerY , width: 206, height: 34))

Comment: See my comment above.